# Creating a team without an organization membership

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I am collaborating on an iOS app with another person, and we both have individual (not organization) memberships. We would like to create a team together so that we can work on an app together without having to switch back and forth between development teams each time one of us opens the app in Xcode.

It is also problematic that we are not on a development team together since we need certificates for notifications, and these notifications are managed by the Apple Ids/accounts that created them.

I have looked through Apple's developer website, and I found that you can create a team if you have an organization membership. However, neither I nor the person I am collaborating with are in a position to do this (we are not members of organizations with DUNS number).

Is it possible to create a team of comprised of multiple individuals with an individual membership? If so, how?

Comment: @shallowThought, how? I couldn't find out, nor could my friend.

Comment: @shallowThought, but then how do I get that team into Xcode?

Comment: @shallowThought, is there a way to find out for sure? Are you sure that this can be done with an individual membership (not organization)

Comment: @shallowThought, I trying to create a team with profiles and certificates than my friend and I can share since we are working on an app together. I added my friend under "Users and Roles" in iTunesConnect as a "Developer", and I assigned him to the app we are working on. Unfortunately, I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible for non-organizations:

> If you have an organization membership in the Apple Developer Program, you can add people to your team and assign them roles, thereby granting them levels of access to team assets.
>
> ...
>
> If you’re enrolled in the Apple Developer Program as an individual, team management tasks ... don't apply.

From [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html).